# Why printStackTrace is not recommended in ATG?

Tags: java, atg

Why printStackTrace is not recommended to use in oracle ATG. If anyone knows please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid printStackTrace(); use a logger call instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477607/avoid-printstacktrace-use-a-logger-call-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the use `printStackTrace` is not just limited to ATG but should be applied to JAVA development in general. The `SonarQube` validation rules explains it as follow:

> Throwable.printStackTrace(...) prints a throwable and its stack trace
>   to some stream. Loggers should be used instead to print throwables, as
>   they have many advantages:

- Users are able to easily retrieve the logs.
- The format of log messages is uniform and allow users to browse the logs easily

> 

With the availability of `logError` you are able to easily spool your error messages, not only to the standard `dynamo.log` and `error.log` but you can also see them in context of the rest of your application logs.

There is another SO question touching the same topic available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477607/avoid-printstacktrace-use-a-logger-call-instead).

Comment: And importantly in an ATG context, you are able to configure if 'logError' is enabled at a component level.