# Log statements in JAVA

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between logger.info and logger.debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342280/difference-between-logger-info-and-logger-debug)

When I should use Log.INFO and Log.DEBUG to print log statements in JAVA?
Can I have some example for these Logs.
I also need a clarification with the log, while displaying Balance whether I need to use Log.INFO or Log.DEBUG

```
Log.write("BALANCE"+bal, Log.INFO);
```

Comment: I need clarification for the given log statement

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve with the log statement. You can look at the question for which your question was marked as exact duplicate. There are good explanations there.

Comment: And for next time: Just search for what you want to ask before asking it. Chances are that somebody already asked it.