# htmlunit crashes when trying to load javascript page

Tags: exception, web-crawler, htmlunit

I've written the following code:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://sb.bpsgameserver.com/?token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&sid=604&lc=de&tz=W.+Europe+Standard+Time&dc=EUR&c=de-DE&pagemenuheaderurl=https%3a%2f%2fsportsbook.betsson.com%2fde%2fPageMenuHeader.aspx&mainpromourl=https%3a%2f%2fsportsbook.betsson.com%2fde%2fMainPromo.aspx&articleurl=https%3a%2f%2fsportsbook.betsson.com%2fde%2f&sidebarpromourl=https%3a%2f%2fsportsbook.betsson.com%2fde%2fSidebarPromo.aspx&proxyurl=https%3a%2f%2fsportsbook.betsson.com%2fScript%2fCross-frame%2fproxy.html&minigamesurl=https%3a%2f%2fsportsbook.betsson.com%2fde%2fMiniGameLauncher.aspx");
```

However, when executing this piece of code html unit crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking setInnerHTML
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:959)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:347)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:425)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:376)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:361)
    at WebpageCrawler.main(WebpageCrawler.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking setInnerHTML
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:295)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$RelinkedSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2796)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2479)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1569)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1564)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1253)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (https://bps.hs.llnwd.net/e2/bc/Betsson/Sportsbook/de/df/2013/10/df_Libs_v126.js#8)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1062)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrameElement.loadInnerPageIfPossible(BaseFrameElement.java:174)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrameElement.loadInnerPage(BaseFrameElement.java:112)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadFrames(HtmlPage.java:1875)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.registerSnippetParsingEnd(HtmlPage.java:2198)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseFragment(HTMLParser.java:174)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseFragment(HTMLParser.java:129)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement.parseHtmlSnippet(HTMLElement.java:1105)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement.setInnerHTML(HTMLElement.java:1004)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:120)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (https://bps.hs.llnwd.net/e2/bc/Betsson/Sportsbook/de/df/2013/10/df_Libs_v126.js#8)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError3(ScriptRuntime.java:3630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable.isReadOnlySettable(SimpleScriptable.java:462)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:259)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2796)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2479)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1569)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1564)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1253)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:118)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 88 more
Enclosed exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking setInnerHTML
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:295)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$RelinkedSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2796)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2479)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1569)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1564)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1253)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:959)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:347)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:425)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:376)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:361)
    at WebpageCrawler.main(WebpageCrawler.java:30)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (https://bps.hs.llnwd.net/e2/bc/Betsson/Sportsbook/de/df/2013/10/df_Libs_v126.js#8)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:570)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1062)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:409)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:286)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:683)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:642)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3116)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2083)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:899)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:242)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:437)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrameElement.loadInnerPageIfPossible(BaseFrameElement.java:174)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.BaseFrameElement.loadInnerPage(BaseFrameElement.java:112)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadFrames(HtmlPage.java:1875)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.registerSnippetParsingEnd(HtmlPage.java:2198)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseFragment(HTMLParser.java:174)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseFragment(HTMLParser.java:129)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement.parseHtmlSnippet(HTMLElement.java:1105)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement.setInnerHTML(HTMLElement.java:1004)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:120)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (https://bps.hs.llnwd.net/e2/bc/Betsson/Sportsbook/de/df/2013/10/df_Libs_v126.js#8)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError3(ScriptRuntime.java:3630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable.isReadOnlySettable(SimpleScriptable.java:462)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:259)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2796)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2479)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1569)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1564)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1253)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:118)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:561)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 88 more
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

What is happening here? Why does it crash?

Answer (score 1):

try this `webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);`

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks.
It's probably a better idea to fix the script errors but in my current situation I'm unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The page you're fetching has JavaScript errors. When HtmlUnit tries to parse the page and execute the JavaScript it encounters those errors and throws the corresponding exception. The error es clearly:

> Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all.

I'd recommend you debug that on the server and fix the JavaScript, as that is what HtmlUnit is there for :)

Comment: Okay, so it is not possible do make htmlunit more tolerant? BTW: I have no access to the server or am anyhow responsible for the page itself, so I cannot repair the javascript :(

Comment: There aren't many options then. The funny thing is that in some cases the webpages still work. You should could try to use it as if there are no errors in it. You can disable the output of errors as stated in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600557/turning-htmlunit-warnings-off/18563576#18563576). Also make sure you have the lastest HtmlUnit version (version 2.13 was released a matter of days ago).