# Bad input type: "email", creating a text input error when use HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: selenium, htmlunit-driver, firefox-driver

I am login into google plus using selenium htmlunit driver. below code is working fine with fireFox driver. When I use HtmlUnitDriver, it gives some error like "**Bad input type:**"

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get("https://plus.google.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("hjhj@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("qwert");
driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: on which line it is giving error, can you post your stack trace.

Comment: "Bad input type" is INFO or ERROR in the console?

Answer (score 1):

From trying your code I saw a message that matched your description.

```
Mar 01, 2016 11:39:28 AM    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input
```

HtmlUnit likes to fill the console up with logging, if you add these lines

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
```

In the static or main it will turn of the logging from htmlunit 
(or see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600557/turning-htmlunit-warnings-off))