# Play 2.5 and Fluentlenium: how to turn HtmlUnit warnings off

Tags: java, selenium, playframework, fluentlenium

I am trying to write Selenium Tests using `WithBrowser` class of the PlayFramework 2.5.

Something like this:

```
public class BrowserFunctionalTest extends WithBrowser {

   @Test
   public void runInBrowser() {
      browser.goTo("/");
      assertNotNull(browser.$("title").getText());
  }
}
```

However, I want to be able to set custom Error Handlers for at least CSS errors, since they spam my console. And since they come from boostrap I cannot get rid of them.

I tried to set the loglevel of the logger like this:

```
 java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);    
System.getProperties().put("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog", "fatal");
```

Fluentlenium documentation tells me to override the `getDefaultDriver` method, but that does not seem to be applicable here. And I cannot get my hands on the WebClient directly, since there is no getter for the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `WithBrowser` helper class, you can override `provideBrowser` to customize how the `TestBrowser` is configured. There are some other details, but the code below pretty much shows how to do it:

```
import static  org.junit.Assert.*;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import play.test.Helpers;
import play.test.TestBrowser;
import play.test.WithBrowser;

public class BrowserFunctionalTest extends WithBrowser {

    // Just to make the WebClient visible at the test. Of course, this
    // could be an independent class to be reused by other tests or you
    // can create your own class that extends WithBrowser and hide all
    // the details from your tests.
    public static class CustomHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {
        @Override
        public WebClient getWebClient() {
            return super.getWebClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected TestBrowser provideBrowser(int port) {
        // Here you need to create the TestBrowser for the class above.
        TestBrowser browser = Helpers.testBrowser(CustomHtmlUnitDriver.class, port);
        CustomHtmlUnitDriver driver = (CustomHtmlUnitDriver)browser.getDriver();
        WebClient client = driver.getWebClient();

        // do whatever you want with the WebClient

        return browser;
    }

    @Test
    public void runInBrowser() {
        browser.goTo("/");
        assertNotNull(browser.$("title").getText());
    }
}
```

Now, since you already have access to the `WebClient`, you can follow the instructions from this discussion:

[Turning HtmlUnit Warnings off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600557/turning-htmlunit-warnings-off)