# [+], [-], [i]... Coding Conventions

Tags: c, coding-style, convention

I have spent time coding a nice console App for windows users. It is 'console-based' so I wanted to make sure it looks professional when displaying messages to the user. I have seen many exploit code or linux codes displaying console information in this manner:

```
[+] Found 5 Wireless Networks!
[+] Now Commencing Attack...
[-] Couldn't load the dictionary file
....
[i] Your wifi has weak security
```

This is just an example. I wanted to know if  there's a convention in using this [+] etc symbols while displaying messages or taking input in console applications.

I hope this is not silly, I just want my code to look professional coz I have worked hard writing the code.

Comment: Not a convention I've ever seen before. I agree with TheCodeArtist about the apparent intent, since that sort of division is used by the logging conventions I *am* familiar with. I guess my own recommendation is simply to pick something clear and use it consistently.

Comment: Yes I know that and I wouldn't put that in my code. By the way, your comment is totally non constructive and unrelated to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is a convention as such. But in the example above :

- `[+]` seems to be for expected progress indicator logs,
- `[-]` for error logs,
- `[i]` for informative logs.

Take a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021604/319204)** for detailed description of the standard log-levels. You may want to map additional descriptive characters to each log-level as was done in the above example..

Comment: Yea I gathered as much that the apparent intent is to show progress/error/info. I just wanted to know if there are some unsaid rules that the community follows while coding such console apps. I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this (or other suitable replacement characters) will not (or at least should not) greatly influence how people perceive the level of professionalism of your code.