# What is the best way to debug a java application in jboss and eclipse if application has multiple modules and each module is separate project

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm working on a java application which has multiple projects. So while debugging we are writing main method and calling required method from it which is increasing the time of development or fixing defects. I want to know the best way to debug if we have multiple java projects and use jboss app server

Comment: actually best way to debug is a good logging system. But executing server in debug mode and adding some breakpoints into the code you want to watch will do the job.

Comment: If I have multiple java projects then should I add Jboss server in eclipse and add multiple projects into it and start it in debug mode?

Comment: yes... that's the usual way, but depending your scenario you may have problems with performance or syncronization, then logging system will be your friend, if you need more info check [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/10-tips-proper-application-logging.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839565/logging-levels-logback-rule-of-thumb-to-assign-log-levels)

Comment: Are all modules maven based? If yes then you can add those dependencies in respective projects and start debugging. Control will jump to a project once execution is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the below

1. Enable remote debugging in JBoss

   Windows - Un-comment below line in *standalone.conf.bat* file

   **`rem set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"`**

   Linux - Change ***DEBUG_MODE=false*** to ***DEBUG_MODE=true*** in *standalone.sh* file

   Connect to jboss from IDE and use breakpoints to debug.
2. Use extensive logging to easily detect what went wrong
3. Or use [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). I heard it supports live reloading and remote code deployment. It will speed up the development

Comment: In JBOSS 5 I dont have standalone.conf.bat.I have run.bat in this way
_"x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" (
  set "JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME%"
) else (
  set "JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% %JAVA_OPTS%"
)_

**please let me know what changes needs to be done for remote debugging in JBoss 5**