# in production code, what's the log level when failing to validate request parameters or format

Tags: java, logging

as titled.
in production code, what's the log level when failing to validate request parameters or format ?

I confuse this puzzle base on two points:

(1) if I log it to error. I concern if one hacker to send too many error requests will cause our APP log two many error log.

(2) but if I log it to debug or lower levels. I concern I can't track issue effectively due to  in production app, log will be setted to warn.

So what's my choose?

Comment: +1. Good question. If this is something that can happen to a regular user in normal use (i.e. a bug in your application), then showing an error page with enough information (that he can print out) to show to support is also an option.

Comment: my puzzle is base on the backend server, not web page. Thanks, you hasn't point which log level I should set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If its a validation failure due to no system error, but invalid input data, I would log as info or warning. If you have a problem such as a system exception, for example a db connection failure or a null pointer, then log error.  Otherwise, an input validation isn't necessarily constituted as an Error
and is a business-as-usual type of occurrence, hence Info level.

In the case of a hacker running a script over and over sending "too many requests", this may be categorized as a Denial-of-service attack.  In this case you need to ensure your firewall software is set to filter those, and I wouldn't worry about it in the app log.

Finally, if a hacker isn't bombarding your system quite at the denial-of-service threshold, then you may need to write some logic to catch this kind of "bad validation" and log an error with a clear error message which you'll know to look for, i.e. a special kind of error.  One such example would be a sql injection attack, which form validation may catch (and some layer in your app must definitely catch).

Depending on the kind of logging framework that you use, you may be able to define your own error level or error category for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

[In my programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874474/545127), I used the error log level (or the word "error" in a message) to indicate that the program failed to do "what it has been instructed to do". So, is this a failure to do "as instructed"? I use the warning log level to report unusual things that are likely (but not certain) to indicate a problem somewhere.

Where are these "request parameters" coming from? If this is a client-server system (a web application?), and the requests are coming from clients, the server has been instructed to "serve clients". What is the server meant (specified/designed) to do if a client sends an invalid request? Probably, to reject the request and return a rejection message to the client. In that case, the server would be in error only if it failed to reject the request or to return the message. That is, only a bug in the server would count as an "error". Would I report invalid request parameters at the warning level? If I also provided the client programs, then an invalid request would suggest a bug in the client program, so I log it as a warning. If clients are uncontrolled (web browsers, for example), I would not report it as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say neither.  I'd write requests to a database so I can query them all the time.  Logs tend to be dumping grounds that are hard to decipher when there are problems.  I always want to see requests and responses when they come in.

As for hackers and denial of service, you'll have to build in logic to detect and stop it.  Your rules will have to distinguish between high traffic from random sources (a good thing) and one or more malicious sources acting in concert.  Do you think you can do that?

Comment: Writing to a db is expensive compare to writing to a file. I wouldn't recommend it for any performance intensive public app unless absolutely necessary and if you have proper hardware.  Grep is just as effective to sift through logs as a SQL.

Comment: It need not delay the client if it's an asynch operation.