# What content/parts shoud a log message consist of?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, java.util.logging

I use java.util.logging and plan to use log4j 2.0 in current projects. Now, that I'm going to use logging more seriously I would like to get some advice from experienced developers what content/parts should go into a log message (date,time,level,source,message,...) to ease later analysis and interpretation of log messages.
Any advice?

Comment: This may be useful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-log-level-warn-vs-error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-log-level-warn-vs-error

Comment: Hi, the referenced SO entry was basically about the right log level. My question is mode general, i.e. regarding all parts of the log entry, i.e. which date/time format, source file/package/class, message details (and its format) .... I'm asking this here because I would like to ease any later analysis (possibly using LogStach, ElasticSearch, ...)

Comment: You just try, see what works and keep that, see what does not work, and change that. Lather, rinse, repeat.