# Eclipse Debug mode : Console output isn't working

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output

I'm working in an enterprise that have an update on their application everyday.

I did an update yesterday because I haven't done it for a while. But there's an huge problem for me, developper, now: the standard output on the Eclipse Console doesn't come anymore after a dozen of lines, and I don't udnerstand why.

Indeed, here's the output when the problem come:

```
[02/08/2016 10:27:21] Info : Reading /me/test.properties property file
[02/08/2016 10:27:21] Info : Reading /me/test2.properties property file
[02/08/2016 10:27:21] Info : Reading /me/test3.version property file
[02/08/2016 10:27:21] Info : Connection to NamingService on host server  with port 14010
-- listing properties --
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=4444
org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=com.sun.corba.se.internal.iiop.ORB
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=server
org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.sun.corba.se.internal.iiop.ORB
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/myDir/myFile.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/myDir2/myFile2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

And after that, I can't have normal output (and before I don't know but the fact that there is the Date and the hour is a good sign.

For example, if I do a little `System.out.println("Hi")` it's not printed. And believe me, in that project, there's a LOT of Debug output that's supposed to be printed.

If you know why or if you think you can help me,

Thank you, Clément.

Comment: Did you try fixing the SLF4J multiple binding issue that may prevent logging from working?

Comment: I tried :) I posted a message on this forum but .. ! 
If you have an idea.

Comment: Yeah, remove one of them.

Comment: In ly pom.xml file, I have nothing. I'm supposed to get two LSF4J jar of something like that but no one is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

You will find your print console statements redirected into the logs. If they are not there is because standard output has been disabled. Use `log.xxx` to get info from your app.

---

**LONG ANSWER:**

Force console output redirect to logs OR just avoid it via general configuration is an usual behaviour. A lot of companies, senior programmers or technical managers avoid output per console to force developers to write / read all application messages via logs by redirecting or disabling standard output.

**THEY DO BECAUSE...**

...using standard outputs are a common mistake made by junior programmers.

**WHY?**

Because this avoid

- bad programming techniques
- lose of info when running in production
- performance issues

**HOW TO SOLVE IT?**

Don't use standard outputs, use `log.info`, `log.debug` or [what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels/2031209#2031209) instead `System.out` or `System.err`.

Comment: I don't think that the output are in logs. But i'll enquire.

How can I check my log4j configuration? :)

Comment: which IDE are you using? you get config from central or local? *I don't think that the output are in logs*.  Why you think so? for me sounds like an usual behaviour.... or are in logs, or they are nowhere. **you should't use `System.out` in big projects** so senior programmers avoid it. About log4j config it depends, first of all, check your logs, if you cannot find `Hi` try executing `log.info("HI");` after `System.out.println("Hi")` and check again

Comment: Found it! Thank you, a lot :) Good continuation

Comment: glad to hear that... You will get used to it, this is a typical way of working, and you will see is more effective (at least when working with more people)

Comment: Yes, i'm sure it's better. But why it's redirected in a log file whereas it was in Console, before? (without an update or modification of the code). 

Do you think the LSF4J binding can be the problem?

Comment: And once again, thank you. I found why this was redirected. They put a "appName.log.dir=xxxxx". My bad.

Comment: @Souin yes... central configuration!!! better don't change or will be reverted in next update. Just start logging, for more info, take a look at one of my preferred answers in SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/2031209/3850595

Answer (score 0):

In server settings-common tab check if allocate console is checked or not

[image: You have to check the checkbox for getting the output in console]

Comment: Where is it please? 
Clément.

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: I found. See the post of @Jordi Castilla

Comment: nice to hear that you found out :)