# Java - stop the Info / Init printing to console

Tags: java, json, console

I have a Java project where I'm using multiple .jar files, and multiple classes. The project itself runs with the desired output - that's not where the issue lies.It uses Java, JSON, external API and local host.

Midway through running the program, the console prints the following (see attached image):

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening, and to perhaps silence it from showing as output? It obviously doesn't look very appealing when using the program!

Many thanks!

Comment: set log level to error

Comment: @Deadpool! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Deadpool for this suggestion - I'm not sure if this is exactly what was suggested, but it works for me.

In the main .java file, I added:

```
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

and then at the top of my main, I added:

```
    Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

There is probably a more specific approach to this (i.e. not just getting every logger), but I thought I would post what works in case anyone else comes across this who is desperate for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

James, what you have implemented is the highest order of fatality in logging and what Deadpool suggested is the second level.

Different log level are described here: [When to use the different log levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels)

If you want to switch this off completely in all scenarios,

```
Logger.getRootLogger("").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```