# build.gradle java Forge 1.16.5 "Cannot resolve symbol 'Date'"

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

I want to code my own minecraft mod and i am following a youtube tutorial.
i did everything right, but in IntelliJ IDEA in the build.gradle file it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'Date'"

here is the full code of the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '4.1.+', changing: true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
// Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '1.0'
group = 'netjackboi03.forestportal' // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = 'forestportal'

java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8) // Mojang ships Java 8 to end users, so your mod should target Java 8.

println('Java: ' + System.getProperty('java.version') + ' JVM: ' + System.getProperty('java.vm.version') + '(' + System.getProperty('java.vendor') + ') Arch: ' + System.getProperty('os.arch'))
minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // Channel:   Version:
    // snapshot   YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable     #          Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // official   MCVersion  Official field/method names from Mojang mapping files
    //
    // You must be aware of the Mojang license when using the 'official' mappings.
    // See more information here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md
    //
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'official', version: '1.16.5'
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.
    
    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be changed as needed. 
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                forestportal {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be changed as needed. 
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                forestportal {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be changed as needed. 
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            // Specify the modid for data generation, where to output the resulting resource, and where to look for existing resources.
            args '--mod', 'forestportal', '--all',
                '--existing', file('src/main/resources').toString(),
                '--existing', file('src/generated/resources').toString(),
                '--output', file('src/generated/resources/')

            mods {
                forestportal {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Include resources generated by data generators.
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use, If this is any group other then 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency. And it's patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.0.58'

    // You may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs or you may define them like so..
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    // Real examples
    // compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    // compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // The 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
    // provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // These dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
    // deobf 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading by the runtime..
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
            "Specification-Title": "forestportal",
            "Specification-Vendor": "examplemodsareus",
            "Specification-Version": "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
            "Implementation-Title": project.name,
            "Implementation-Version": "${version}",
            "Implementation-Vendor" :"examplemodsareus",
            "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

// Example configuration to allow publishing using the maven-publish task
// This is the preferred method to reobfuscate your jar file
jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar') 
// However if you are in a multi-project build, dev time needs unobfed jar files, so you can delay the obfuscation until publishing by doing
//publish.dependsOn('reobfJar')

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies in this line of code:

```
"Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

I don't know if this is significant to run the mod, but i wanted to make sure it isn't.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I need to say that I don't know. On 1.16.4 it works perfectly, but I have no idea why this don't work on 1.16.5. Maybe try to delete this line and then see if everything works well without this line.