# building mod does not include mcmod.info (1.12.2)

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

posting here as 1.12.2 is no longer officially supported by forge,

trying to build my first mod and I'm having troubles getting it to be detected by gradle

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // These repositories are only for Gradle plugins, put any other repositories in the repository block further below
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1.+', changing: true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'

group = 'AvalonMods'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    archivesBaseName = 'RuneTech'
    toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
}

minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time and must be in the following format.
    // Channel:   Version:
    // snapshot   YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable     #          Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // official   MCVersion  Official field/method names from Mojang mapping files
    //
    // You must be aware of the Mojang license when using the 'official' mappings.
    // See more information here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md
    //
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. They may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'stable', version: '39-1.12'

    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                runetech {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                runetech {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Include resources generated by data generators.
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

repositories {
    // Put repositories for dependencies here
    // ForgeGradle automatically adds the Forge maven and Maven Central for you

    // If you have mod jar dependencies in ./libs, you can declare them as a repository like so:
    // flatDir {
    //     dir 'libs'
    // }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use. If this is any group other than 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency, and its patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2855'

    // Real mod deobf dependency examples - these get remapped to your current mappings
    // compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}:${jei_version}:api") // Adds JEI API as a compile dependency
    // runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}:${jei_version}") // Adds the full JEI mod as a runtime dependency
    // implementation fg.deobf("com.tterrag.registrate:Registrate:MC${mc_version}-${registrate_version}") // Adds registrate as a dependency

    // Examples using mod jars from ./libs
    // implementation fg.deobf("blank:coolmod-${mc_version}:${coolmod_version}")

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html
}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading at runtime.
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                "Specification-Title"     : "runetech",
                "Specification-Vendor"    : "Kital_Stargazer",
                "Specification-Version"   : "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
                "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                "Implementation-Version"  : project.jar.archiveVersion,
                "Implementation-Vendor"   : "Kital_Stargazer",
                "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar')
```

mcmod.info

```json
[
  {
    "modid": "runetech",
    "name": "Rune Tech",
    "description": "A technological approach to magic",
    "version": "${version}",
    "mcversion": "${mcversion}",
    "url": "",
    "updateUrl": "",
    "authorList": [
      "Kital_Stargazer"
    ],
    "credits": "Inspired by: Thaumcraft (v4.2.3.5), Immersive Engineering, Embers, and more",
    "logoFile": "",
    "screenshots": [],
    "dependencies": []
  }
]
```

it otherwise works it's just the mcmod.info that is being stubborn.

mcmod.info is in src/main/resources, build.gradle is (to my knowledge) correctly formatted as well as mcmod.info

the mod is otherwise very bare bones at the moment so there is little that could be causing an issue

Comment: Where did you get your build.gradle from, and/or why did you modify it the way you did? It looks very different than the one in the MDK.

Comment: Also, can you confirm by looking in the jar file that the mcmod.info actually isn't in there anywhere, rather than it being there but Forge just not recognizing it?

Comment: i didn't use the MDK, i used a pre-generated one from an IntelliJ IDEA plugin also the mcmod.info is making it in it's just not being recognized

Comment: Is the mcmod.info in the root of the jar file? And how are you building the mod, `./gradlew build` or something else? Also, is your mod available on GitHub or anywhere else, so that others can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: mcmod.info is in the root of the jar, `./gradlew build` then `./gradlew runClient`. also the source is available here on github https://github.com/Kitsune-Ultima/RuneTech

Comment: If you take the jar out of `build/libs/` and try it in a regular (non-development) Forge instance, does that work?

Comment: ok so it works outside of the dev environment but the `${version}` doesn't get updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239623/discussion-between-tuvanen-kiruitsu-and-joseph-sible-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, then add to the end of the file build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}

task prepareAssets(type: Copy) {
    group = 'build'
    from project.file('src/main/resources')
    into project.file('build/classes/java/main')
}

classes.dependsOn(prepareAssets)
```

This should help the collector find the resources of your mod.