# Minecraft forge genVSCodeRuns failed because of null pointer

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft

I code a mod with VSCode. I want to generate the runs to be able to debug.
It works when I run:
`prepareRunClient` and then
`runClient`
when I try to run genVSCodeRuns this error appears:

```
Execution failed for task ':genVSCodeRuns'.
> Cannot invoke "org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseModel.getClasspath()" because "eclipse" is null
```

I tried to find answers, but I cannot find one.
Note:
downgrading java is not practical for me.

versions:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-02-08 09:58:38 UTC
Revision:     f0d9291c04b90b59445041eaa75b2ee744162586

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // These repositories are only for Gradle plugins, put any other repositories in the repository block further below
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1.+', changing: true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'

group = 'de.wroracer'
// MCVERSION-MAJORMOD.MAJORAPI.MINOR.PATCH
version = '1.18.1-0.0.1.0'

java {
    archivesBaseName = 'JustEnoughTNT'
    toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
}

minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time and must be in the following format.
    // Channel:   Version:
    // snapshot   YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable     #          Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // official   MCVersion  Official field/method names from Mojang mapping files
    //
    // You must be aware of the Mojang license when using the 'official' mappings.
    // See more information here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md
    //
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. They may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'official', version: '1.18.1'

    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                justenoughtnt {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                justenoughtnt {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/removed as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            // Specify the modid for data generation, where to output the resulting resource, and where to look for existing resources.
            args '--mod', 'justenoughtnt', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/'), '--existing', file('src/main/resources/')

            mods {
                justenoughtnt {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Include resources generated by data generators.
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

repositories {
    // Put repositories for dependencies here
    // ForgeGradle automatically adds the Forge maven and Maven Central for you

    // If you have mod jar dependencies in ./libs, you can declare them as a repository like so:
    // flatDir {
    //     dir 'libs'
    // }
    maven {
        // location of the maven that hosts JEI files
        name = "Progwml6 maven"
        url = "https://dvs1.progwml6.com/files/maven/"
    }
    maven {
        // location of a maven mirror for JEI files, as a fallback
        name = "ModMaven"
        url = "https://modmaven.dev"
    }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/silentchaos512/silentlib")
        credentials {
            username = property('gpr.username')
            password = property('gpr.token')
        }
    }
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/silentchaos512/silent-utils")
        credentials {
            username = property('gpr.username')
            password = property('gpr.token')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use. If this is any group other than 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency, and its patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.18.1-39.0.63'

    // Real mod deobf dependency examples - these get remapped to your current mappings
     compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}:${jei_version}:api") // Adds JEI API as a compile dependency
     runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}:${jei_version}") // Adds the full JEI mod as a runtime dependency
    // implementation fg.deobf("com.tterrag.registrate:Registrate:MC${mc_version}-${registrate_version}") // Adds registrate as a dependency

    // Examples using mod jars from ./libs
    // implementation fg.deobf("blank:coolmod-${mc_version}:${coolmod_version}")

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

    implementation fg.deobf("net.silentchaos512:silent-lib:1.18-6.0.0") {
        exclude module: "forge"
    }
}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading at runtime.
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                "Specification-Title"     : "justenoughtnt",
                "Specification-Vendor"    : "WRORacer",
                "Specification-Version"   : "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
                "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                "Implementation-Version"  : project.jar.archiveVersion,
                "Implementation-Vendor"   : "WRORacer",
                "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar')
```

[here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/733635246846640198/952886716782506014/stacktrace.txt) is the full stacktrace with arg `--stacktrace`
I did the link because the post is exceeding stack overflow's max char limit

Comment: Can you show your gradle file ?

Comment: @Elikill58 edited post to include Gradle file

Comment: Ok thanks. There is something that I don't understand: it's mentionned eclipse plugin, but in your code there isn't any eclipse mention

Comment: @Elikill58 if you are interested I added the full stacktrace in the post

Comment: Oh ok. I think you should check for another versions of ForgeGradle or add issue on [ForgeGradle](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/issues)