# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Temurin\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build.gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to add other minecraft mods as dependencies in the mod I've been working on with Intellij Idea, but when I try to launch Minecraft, it always fails and gives an error I don't understand.

Here's the error

```
> Task :runClient FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Temurin\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

    * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1m 26s

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no]
```

**And here's my build.gradle file**

```
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
        mavenCentral()

        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1.+', changing: true


    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
// Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '1.16.5-1.0'
group = 'com.pinwheel.singlet' // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = 'singlet'


java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8) // Mojang ships Java 8 to end users, so your mod should target Java 8.

repositories {
    maven {
        // location of the maven that hosts JEI files
        name = "Progwml6 maven"
        url = "https://dvs1.progwml6.com/files/maven/"
    }
    maven {
        // location of a maven mirror for JEI files, as a fallback
        name = "ModMaven"
        url = "https://modmaven.k.4u.nl"
    }
}
println('Java: ' + System.getProperty('java.version') + ' JVM: ' + System.getProperty('java.vm.version') + '(' + System.getProperty('java.vendor') + ') Arch: ' + System.getProperty('os.arch'))
minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // Channel:   Version:
    // snapshot   YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable     #          Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // official   MCVersion  Official field/method names from Mojang mapping files
    //
    // You must be aware of the Mojang license when using the 'official' mappings.
    // See more information here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md
    //
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20210309-1.16.5'
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.
    
    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be changed as needed.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN, REGISTRIES, REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'


            mods {
                singlet {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be changed as needed.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                singlet {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }

            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be changed as needed.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'
            property "mixin.env.remapRefMap", "true"
            property "mixin.env.refMapRemappingFile", "buildFile.parent/build/createSrgToMcp/output.srg"

            // Specify the modid for data generation, where to output the resulting resource, and where to look for existing resources.
            args '--mod', 'singlet', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/'), '--existing', file('src/main/resources/')

            mods {
                singlet {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Include resources generated by data generators.
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use, If this is any group other then 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
    // that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency. And it's patches will be applied.
    // The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.2.20'

    // compile against the JEI API but do not include it at runtime
    compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-1.16.5:7.7.1.152:api")
    // at runtime, use the full JEI jar
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-1.16.5:7.7.1.152")
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['jei-1.16.5-7.7.1.152.jar'])
    runtimeOnly fg.deobf("curse.maven:abnormalscore-382216:3607198")



    // You may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs or you may define them like so..
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    // compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    // Real examples
    // compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    // compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // The 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
    // provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // These dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
    // deobf 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // For more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    maven { url "https://maven.jaackson.me" }
    maven { url "https://dvs1.progwml6.com/files/maven/" }
    maven { url "https://modmaven.k-4u.nl" }
    maven { url "https://www.cursemaven.com"}
}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading by the runtime..
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
            "Specification-Title": "singlet",
            "Specification-Vendor": "",
            "Specification-Version": "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
            "Implementation-Title": project.name,
            "Implementation-Version": "${version}",
            "Implementation-Vendor" :"",
            "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"),
                "MixinConfigs": project.name + ".mixins.json"
        ])
    }
}

// Example configuration to allow publishing using the maven-publish task
// This is the preferred method to reobfuscate your jar file
jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar') 
// However if you are in a multi-project build, dev time needs unobfed jar files, so you can delay the obfuscation until publishing by doing
//publish.dependsOn('reobfJar')

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the gradle, it will end up as successful, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Please be patient with me, as English is not my first language.

Comment: Can you please show the full build log?