# When to use which log level in Rust tracing?

Tags: logging, rust, rust-tracing

I started using [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) and other logging libraries in Rust. They have macros (`trace`, `debug`, `info`, `warn`, `error`) to emit logs at different levels.

When should I use which one of them?

I saw some examples in the library docs and `info`, `warn`, `error` are pretty straight-forward but `trace` and `debug` are very similar and I don't know where I should use them.

Comment: I suggest reading related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels?rq=2