# How to make NLog stop writing redundant information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

My `Programm.cs`:

```
var logger = LogManager.Setup()
    .RegisterNLogWeb()
    .LoadConfigurationFromFile("nlog.config")
    .GetCurrentClassLogger();

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddControllers(options => { options.Filters.Add<LogResponseFilterAttribute>(); 
    });
    
    builder.Services.AddScoped<LogResponseFilterAttribute>();

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);

    builder.Host.UseNLog();

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.Error(e, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

My `nlog.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogFile="c:\logs\internal-log.txt">

    <variable name="iis_sitename" value="${gdc:item=iis_sitename}"/>
    <variable name="logDirectory" value="c:/logs/${iis_sitename}"/>
    <variable name="logSourceName" value="dpc"/>

    <targets async="true">
        <target xsi:type="File"
                name="jsonFile"
                fileName="${logDirectory}/${logSourceName}-${lowercase:${level}}.jsonl"
                archiveFileName="${logDirectory}/archives/${logSourceName}-${lowercase:${level}}_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.jsonl"
                archiveAboveSize="1000240"
                archiveNumbering="Sequence"
                archiveEvery="Day"
                concurrentWrites="true"
                keepFileOpen="true"
                maxArchiveFiles="1"
                encoding="UTF-8">
            <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout"
                    includeAllProperties="true"
                    maxRecursionLimit="2"
                    suppressSpaces="true">
                <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message}"/>
            </layout>
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonFile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

How do I call it in an action:

```
[HttpGet("products")]
    public Task<object?> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromQuery] Filter filter)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello world!");
         ... other stuff
    }
```

And what I get:

[image]

And I'm confused! What is this? Can I have just my "Hello world"? All this smart stuff looks very cool and probably may be used for a new season of "Mr. Robot", but I do not
need it! I need just my "Hello world"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fundamental concept across all logging libraries is that the **Log *Severity* Level** is the primary filter criteria when you specify the verbosity of the logs that you wish to capture.

> - [LogLevel Class](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/T_NLog_LogLevel.htm)
> - [When to use the different log levels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2031163/1690217)
> - [NLog Tutorial - The essential guide for logging from C#](https://blog.elmah.io/nlog-tutorial-the-essential-guide-for-logging-from-csharp/)

In your `nlog.config` the primary filter for the *[internal log file](https://blog.elmah.io/nlog-tutorial-the-essential-guide-for-logging-from-csharp/#internal-logging)* is defined by the `minlevel` attribute, this is the minimal log level to log. In your case you have specified `Info`, which corresponds to all *Information that highlights progress or application lifetime events.*

- As you can see in the log output, there is a lot of *smart stuff* from the runtime that relates specifically to the lifetime of your http action endpoint.

This first mechanism you should use to differentiate your logs from standard `Info` log messages is to use `_logger.LogWarning` instead of `LogInformation` in your code. Think of warning to mean, "*more important than the standard **Information**, but less than an **Error***". Instead of the dictionary interpretation to mean that something might be wrong or you are close to some sort of error threshold or state.

- Some logging frameworks define a `Notice` level that is higher than `Info` but less than `Warning` that might seem more appropriate but neither MS Logging Extensions nor NLog explicitly support this.

So knowing that the framework and other system tools will report lifetime events using `Info`, by default in your application logic you should use `LogWarning()` to easily differentiate your important messages that are neither `Critical` nor `Error`

```
 _logger.LogWarning("Hello world!");
```

Then in your config rules you can specify `Warn` as the log verbosity:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="jsonFile" />
</rules>
```

You can also use [Rules](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules) that target specific loggers that might be active in your runtime, if you know them. By Convention, internal .Net loggers use the fully qualified class name as the logger name. Knowing this you

> You don't have to *guess* at the logger name that *looks cool, but you think is redundant* if you include it as an attribute in your [layout](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers)
>
> ```
>   <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout"
>           includeAllProperties="true"
>           maxRecursionLimit="2"
>           suppressSpaces="true">
>       <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
>       <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}"/>
>       <attribute name="message" layout="${message}"/>
>   </layout>
> ```

Then you can specify a different `minLevel` for loggers that match your name pattern criteria. Since NLog5 we can use [`finalMinLevel`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel) to simplify the syntax for combining logging rules, the following example will only log `Warn` or higher for common System and Microsoft framework loggers, but still allow `Info` messages from our application runtime to be captured in the log output.

```
<rules>
    <logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonFile" />
</rules>
```

> **NOTE:**
> It is often tempting to *silence* logs from outside of our application logic using `finalMinLevel="None"` but this could lead to you missing critical information if your application fails due to external hosting or environmental events. `finalMinLevel="Warn"` is a conventional standard that means the standard lifetime events will be excluded but any more important information will still be logged.

Comment: Thank you. nlog documentation is a bit convoluted and has not very good structure. Thanks for useful links. And for sharing what is standart what is not. Because I thought these rules were my own invented bicycle.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak If you have suggestions for how to improve the [NLog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules) then you are wellcome to [create an issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues) with ideas for how to make it better.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Notice that it recommended to use `finalMinLevel="Info"` for `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime`-Logger. But if you insist on using `Warn`, then you should just remove the override, since `Microsoft.*`-LoggerPattern is enough alone.

Comment: Good point @RolfKristensen  I agree and do that myself, but OP doesn't want to see that information... I'll work it in

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following rules to my nlog.config:

````
<rules>
        <logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="None" />
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="None" />
        <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="None" />
    ```
````

I use nlog 5+ version.

Comment: See also: https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter