Forge 1.21.1 mod not loading correctly error
According to IntelliJ forge 1.21.1 has deprecated .get() and .get().getModEventBus(), I am wondering if this is why my code is running into errors. If so, how do I now write it? I have tried asking ChatGPT about the new method (kept telling me to use .get().getModEventBus()) and researching (either says the search didn't match any documents or other forge issues and how to install forge) to no avail. I don't believe this is the error and it doesn't matter too much about the .get() as i have seen others using it still in forge 1.21.1.
I have tried launching my mod but it crashes with this error:
Copy-Chat (copychat) has failed to load correctly
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener for event class
net.minecraftforge.event.server.ServerStratingEvent takes an argument that is not a subtype of the base type interface
net.minecraftforge.fml.event.IModBusEvent

Many thanks, Code.
The mod can send different messages, and soon (hopefully) joining and leaving messages. If there are other mods that do the same purpose for forge 1.21.1 I am not really interested as I want to make my own (its about the creativity and challenge it presents, but this is one challenge that I do want and need help with). Granted it is not too realistic right now but I will fix that when this is fixed!
Mod Code:
package com.github.CodeCorruption0.copychat;

import com.mojang.brigadier.Command;
import com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher;
import com.mojang.brigadier.context.CommandContext;
import com.mojang.brigadier.arguments.StringArgumentType;
import net.minecraft.commands.CommandSourceStack;
import net.minecraft.commands.Commands;
import net.minecraft.network.chat.Component;
import net.minecraft.network.chat.Style;
import net.minecraft.network.chat.TextColor;
import net.minecraft.server.level.ServerPlayer;
import net.minecraft.commands.arguments.EntityArgument;
import net.minecraftforge.event.server.ServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

@Mod(CopyChat.MOD_ID)
public class CopyChat {
    public static final String MOD_ID = "copychat";

    public CopyChat() {
        IEventBus modEventBus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();
        modEventBus.addListener(this::onServerStarting);
    }

    private void onServerStarting(ServerStartingEvent event) {
        registerCommands(event.getServer().getCommands().getDispatcher());
    }

    private void registerCommands(CommandDispatcher<CommandSourceStack> dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.register(Commands.literal("copy-chat")
                .then(Commands.literal("Server")
                        .then(Commands.argument("message", StringArgumentType.greedyString())
                                .executes(context -> sendServerMessage(context, StringArgumentType.getString(context, "message")))
                        )
                )
                .then(Commands.literal("Player")
                        .then(Commands.argument("player", EntityArgument.player())
                                .then(Commands.argument("message", StringArgumentType.greedyString())
                                        .executes(context -> sendPlayerMessage(context, EntityArgument.getPlayer(context, "player"), StringArgumentType.getString(context, "message")))
                                )
                        )
                )
                .then(Commands.literal("MSG")
                        .then(Commands.argument("target", EntityArgument.player())
                                .then(Commands.argument("sender", StringArgumentType.string())
                                        .then(Commands.argument("message", StringArgumentType.greedyString())
                                                .executes(context -> sendMessage(context, EntityArgument.getPlayer(context, "target"), StringArgumentType.getString(context, "sender"), StringArgumentType.getString(context, "message")))
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
    }

    private int sendServerMessage(CommandContext<CommandSourceStack> context, String message) {
        context.getSource().sendSuccess((Supplier<Component>) Component.literal("[SERVER] " + message), false);
        return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
    }

    private int sendPlayerMessage(CommandContext<CommandSourceStack> context, ServerPlayer target, String message) {
        target.sendSystemMessage(Component.literal("[Player] " + message));
        return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
    }

    private int sendMessage(CommandContext<CommandSourceStack> context, ServerPlayer target, String sender, String message) {
        target.sendSystemMessage(Component.literal(sender + ": " + message).setStyle(Style.EMPTY.withItalic(true).withColor(TextColor.fromRgb(0xA9A9A9))));
        return Command.SINGLE_SUCCESS;
    }
}

build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id 'net.minecraftforge.gradle' version '[6.0.16,6.2)'
}


group = mod_group_id
version = mod_version

base {
    archivesName = mod_id
}

java {
    toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
}

minecraft {
    // The mappings can be changed at any time and must be in the following format.
    // Channel:   Version:
    // official   MCVersion             Official field/method names from Mojang mapping files
    // parchment  YYYY.MM.DD-MCVersion  Open community-sourced parameter names and javadocs layered on top of official
    //
    // You must be aware of the Mojang license when using the 'official' or 'parchment' mappings.
    // See more information here: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MCPConfig/blob/master/Mojang.md
    //
    // Parchment is an unofficial project maintained by ParchmentMC, separate from MinecraftForge
    // Additional setup is needed to use their mappings: https://parchmentmc.org/docs/getting-started
    //
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. They may not always work.
    // Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings channel: mapping_channel, version: mapping_version

    // When true, this property will have all Eclipse/IntelliJ IDEA run configurations run the "prepareX" task for the given run configuration before launching the game.
    // In most cases, it is not necessary to enable.
    // enableEclipsePrepareRuns = true
    // enableIdeaPrepareRuns = true

    // This property allows configuring Gradle's ProcessResources task(s) to run on IDE output locations before launching the game.
    // It is REQUIRED to be set to true for this template to function.
    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.html
    copyIdeResources = true

    // When true, this property will add the folder name of all declared run configurations to generated IDE run configurations.
    // The folder name can be set on a run configuration using the "folderName" property.
    // By default, the folder name of a run configuration is the name of the Gradle project containing it.
    // generateRunFolders = true

    // This property enables access transformers for use in development.
    // They will be applied to the Minecraft artifact.
    // The access transformer file can be anywhere in the project.
    // However, it must be at "META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg" in the final mod jar to be loaded by Forge.
    // This default location is a best practice to automatically put the file in the right place in the final jar.
    // See https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/latest/advanced/accesstransformers/ for more information.
    // accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    // Default run configurations.
    // These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
    runs {
        // applies to all the run configs below
        configureEach {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            // The markers can be added/remove as needed separated by commas.
            // "SCAN": For mods scan.
            // "REGISTRIES": For firing of registry events.
            // "REGISTRYDUMP": For getting the contents of all registries.
            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'


            // Recommended logging level for the console
            // You can set various levels here.
            // Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031163/when-to-use-the-different-log-levels
            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'
        }

        client {
            // Comma-separated list of namespaces to load gametests from. Empty = all namespaces.
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', mod_id
        }

        server {
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', mod_id
            args '--nogui'
        }

        // This run config launches GameTestServer and runs all registered gametests, then exits.
        // By default, the server will crash when no gametests are provided.
        // The gametest system is also enabled by default for other run configs under the /test command.
        gameTestServer {
            property 'forge.enabledGameTestNamespaces', mod_id
        }

        data {
            // example of overriding the workingDirectory set in configureEach above
            workingDirectory project.file('run-data')

            // Specify the modid for data generation, where to output the resulting resource, and where to look for existing resources.
            args '--mod', mod_id, '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/'), '--existing', file('src/main/resources/')
        }
    }
}

// Include resources generated by data generators.
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

repositories {
    // Put repositories for dependencies here
    // ForgeGradle automatically adds the Forge maven and Maven Central for you

    // If you have mod jar dependencies in ./libs, you can declare them as a repository like so.
    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver
    // flatDir {
    //     dir 'libs'
    // }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify the version of Minecraft to use.
    // Any artifact can be supplied so long as it has a "userdev" classifier artifact and is a compatible patcher artifact.
    // The "userdev" classifier will be requested and setup by ForgeGradle.
    // If the group id is "net.minecraft" and the artifact id is one of ["client", "server", "joined"],
    // then special handling is done to allow a setup of a vanilla dependency without the use of an external repository.
    minecraft "net.minecraftforge:forge:${minecraft_version}-${forge_version}"

    // Example mod dependency with JEI - using fg.deobf() ensures the dependency is remapped to your development mappings
    // The JEI API is declared for compile time use, while the full JEI artifact is used at runtime
    // compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}-common-api:${jei_version}")
    // compileOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}-forge-api:${jei_version}")
    // runtimeOnly fg.deobf("mezz.jei:jei-${mc_version}-forge:${jei_version}")

    // Example mod dependency using a mod jar from ./libs with a flat dir repository
    // This maps to ./libs/coolmod-${mc_version}-${coolmod_version}.jar
    // The group id is ignored when searching -- in this case, it is "blank"
    // implementation fg.deobf("blank:coolmod-${mc_version}:${coolmod_version}")

    // For more info:
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

    // Hack fix for now, force jopt-simple to be exactly 5.0.4 because Mojang ships that version, but some transtive dependencies request 6.0+
    implementation('net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:5.0.4') { version { strictly '5.0.4' } }
}

// This block of code expands all declared replace properties in the specified resource targets.
// A missing property will result in an error. Properties are expanded using ${} Groovy notation.
// When "copyIdeResources" is enabled, this will also run before the game launches in IDE environments.
// See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.html
tasks.named('processResources', ProcessResources).configure {
    var replaceProperties = [minecraft_version   : minecraft_version, minecraft_version_range: minecraft_version_range,
                             forge_version       : forge_version, forge_version_range: forge_version_range,
                             loader_version_range: loader_version_range,
                             mod_id              : mod_id, mod_name: mod_name, mod_license: mod_license, mod_version: mod_version,
                             mod_authors         : mod_authors, mod_description: mod_description,]

    inputs.properties replaceProperties

    filesMatching(['META-INF/mods.toml', 'pack.mcmeta']) {
        expand replaceProperties + [project: project]
    }
}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading at runtime.
tasks.named('jar', Jar).configure {
    manifest {
        attributes(["Specification-Title"     : mod_id,
                    "Specification-Vendor"    : mod_authors,
                    "Specification-Version"   : "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
                    "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version"  : project.jar.archiveVersion,
                    "Implementation-Vendor"   : mod_authors,
                    "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")])
    }

    // This is the preferred method to reobfuscate your jar file
    finalizedBy 'reobfJar'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8' // Use the UTF-8 charset for Java compilation
}

// Merge the resources and classes into the same directory.
// This is done because java expects modules to be in a single directory.
// And if we have it in multiple we have to do performance intensive hacks like having the UnionFileSystem
// This will eventually be migrated to ForgeGradle so modders don't need to manually do it. But that is later.
sourceSets.each {
    def dir = layout.buildDirectory.dir("sourcesSets/$it.name")
    it.output.resourcesDir = dir
    it.java.destinationDirectory = dir
}

